# Airflow does not respect depends_on_past when catchup = True?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an Airflow 2.0 DAG defined with a **start_date** in the past, **catchup = True** and **max_active_runs = 5**.  The goal is to process data from the **start_date** with up to five DAG Runs executing in parallel.

Certain tasks are defined with **depends_on_past = True**, however I observe that they do sometimes execute in parallel and it seems **depends_on_past** is not respected.

Why is this ?  Is it possible to process historical data with parallel DAG Runs, with either **catchup** or **backfill**, and prevent certain tasks in the DAG from executing in parallel ?

Answer (score 2):

**Why is this?**

According to documentation this should not happen. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658594/airflow-depends-on-past-explanation).

**Is it possible to process historical data with parallel DAG Runs, with either catchup or backfill, and prevent certain tasks in the DAG from executing in parallel?**

You would benefit from the [pools](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#pools). Pools allow you to control parallelism on tasks of your choice.
It is referred in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600181/airflow-locking-between-tasks-so-that-only-one-parallel-task-runs-at-a-time) as well.

*P.S. Would have suggested in comments but I can't.*

Answer (score 1):

My bad.  What I omitted is that I have a short-circuit operator in my DAG.  If a Dag Run short circuits and tasks are skipped they treated as success, which triggers downstream tasks that depend on past.

This makes sense - if a task if skipped and not treated as success, future tasks would not execute.